# MS ACCESS: hierarchical value counter

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to ask your help to find some kind of SQL solution in MS ACCESS. 
In this example I have a very simple table, like:

```
ID| Item  
1  | apple  
2 | apple  
3 | peach  
4 | peach  
5 | peach
```

A want to achieve something like an „value hierarchical” counter, like:

```
ID | Item   | Hierarchycounter  
1  | apple | 1  
2  | apple  | 2  
3  | peach | 1  
4  | peach | 2  
5  | peach | 3
```

Is there any way to handle this in Access SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pain in MS Access.  In most databases, you can just use `row_number()`.  For Access, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select id, item,
       (select count(*)
        from simple as s2
        where s2.item = s.item and s2.id <= s.id
       ) as Hierarchycounter
from simple as s;
```